# subprocess error while installing xdman and oracle java8

Tags: dpkg

```
sudo apt-get install xdman
[sudo] password for xxxx: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
xdman is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  thunderbird-globalmenu gir1.2-ubuntuoneui-3.0 libavahi-ui-gtk3-0
  guile-1.8-libs libgdu-gtk0 libubuntuoneui-3.0-1 librhythmbox-core5
  libmusicbrainz3-6
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Setting up oracle-java8-installer (8b108~precise~NoobsLab.com) ...
Downloading Oracle Java 8...
--2014-01-03 00:20:47--  http://www.java.net/download/jdk8/archive/b108/binaries/jdk-8-ea-bin-b108-linux-i586-19_sep_2013.tar.gz
Resolving www.java.net (www.java.net)... failed: Name or service not known.
wget: unable to resolve host address `www.java.net'
download failed
Oracle JDK 8 is NOT installed.
dpkg: error processing oracle-java8-installer (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of xdman:
 xdman depends on oracle-java8-installer | oracle-java7-installer | oracle-java6-installer; however:
  Package oracle-java8-installer is not configured yet.
  Package oracle-java7-installer is not installed.
  Package oracle-java6-installer is not installed.
dpkg: error processing xdman (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:
 oracle-java8-installer
 xdman
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I am getting this error while installing xdman. please help me to resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

We probably can not fix this: http://www.java.net does not exist. It might be down or has ceased to exist but the maintainer of xdman probaly did not change the code or submit a change to the code for it to be included.

Installation of xdman can be done from source like this

```
cd ~/
mkdir xdman
cd xdman
wget -c http://sourceforge.net/projects/xdman/files/xdman.zip/download
unzip download.zip
chmod +x xdman.sh
./xdman.sh
```

This will install xdman but will NOT install Java.  You need to do that separately. Java 7:

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```

Comment: I think a bug report is warranted with this.